# Get request object in class-based View

Tags: django

I want to get the current logged in user in a class-based view. I can do that by extracting the user from the request object, but how can I obtain that object?

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name='home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
        context['username'] =  request.user.username
        return context
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can access to it from `self.request.user`

for example you can do this in your CBV

```
if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
   ...
```

or

```
context['username'] = self.request.user.username
   ...
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Access `self.request.user` as follows:

```
context['username'] = self.request.user
```